# is there a function that is differentiable at $0$ but has no limit at $0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Is there an example of a function $f:\mathbb{R}→ \mathbb{R}$, that is differentiable at $0$ but does not have a limit at $0$.

My initial thoughts was that this does not exist as the definition of a differentiable function includes limits. That is $\displaystyle\lim_{x →0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} $ so if this exists then surely does $\displaystyle\lim_{x→0} f(x)$. But I know do not think this argument follows.

Is there a way there to prove this or an example that does fit these constraints.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit exists v. Differentiable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464326/limit-exists-v-differentiable)

Comment: Differentiability implies continuity and continuity is equivalent to the statement $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=f(0)$.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to0}(f(x)-f(0))=\lim_{x\to 0}x\cdot \lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}x\cdot f'(0)=0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument almost works. By adding some details, you end up proving that if $f$ is differentiable at $0$ then $f$ is continuous at $0$, and therefore $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = f(0)$.

Here's some additional detail.

Knowing that $f'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$ exists, and knowing that $\lim_{x \to 0} x = 0$, by using the product theorem for limits it follows that 
$$\lim_{x \to 0} (f(x)-f(0)) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} \cdot x
$$ 
exists, and furthermore
$$\lim_{x \to 0} (f(x)-f(0)) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} \cdot x = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} \cdot \lim_{x \to 0} x = f'(0) \cdot 0 = 0
$$
Next, knowing that the limit of the constant $f(0)$ exists, and knowing the sum theorem for limits, it follows that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0} ((f(x)-f(0)) + f(0))$ exists, and that
$$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0} ((f(x)-f(0)) + f(0)) = \lim_{x \to 0} (f(x)-f(0)) + \lim_{x \to 0} f(0) = 0 + f(0) = f(0)
$$